# EC2 instance and EDS volume is restarting even after the terminate/delete

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am dealing with this issues for quiet couple of hours and tried all possible ways to delete my EC2 instance that I created for testing/free trail.

Immediately after stopping/terminating the EC2 instance its restarting a new instance with new id.

Also I tried detachingand delete volume after stopping EC2 instance ,which is again restarting with new id pointing to the new EC2 instance that started.
I have default security group assigned to the instance which I can't remove it from it.

is there any other thing that I need to look into

Comment: I was looking at different panel (AWS auto scaling) before ,now I can see an auto scaling group under EC2 . After deleting that group my problem solved and my EC2 instance disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an auto scaling group on the instance. Look under "Auto Scaling" and delete the group there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I don't see any groups under auto scaling.

Comment: I was looking at different panel (AWS auto scaling) before ,now I can see an auto scaling group under EC2 . After deleting that group my problem solved and my EC2 instance disappeared.